# Cython - efficiently filtering a typed memoryview

Tags: python, performance, cython, typed-memory-views

This Cython function returns a random element among the elements of a numpy array that are within certain limits:

```
cdef int search(np.ndarray[int] pool):
  cdef np.ndarray[int] limited
  limited = pool[(pool >= lower_limit) & (pool <= upper_limit)]
  return np.random.choice(limited)
```

This works just fine. However, this function is very critical to the performance of my code. Typed memoryviews are apparently very much faster than numpy arrays, but they cannot be filtered in the same way as above.

How could I write a function that does the same thing as above using typed memoryviews? Or is there another way to improve the performance of the function?

Comment: This expression: `pool[(pool >= lower_limit) & (pool <= upper_limit)]` iterates over the length of `pool` *three times* (materializing three seperate boolean arrays) and that's  before indexing it! Try to use [`numexpr`](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) to avoid the unnecessary copying.

Comment: I think this question is based on a false premise - typed memoryviews are a slightly more modern and general syntax than the `np.ndarray` syntax, but _do not_ give a significantly different speed. (I think I'd try to cache `limited` if possible (if it's the same each time))

Comment: If one assumes that limited are distributed more or less uniformly in the array and one isn't too fussy about the distribution of choosen elements, one just could pick a random index in the array and return the first limited element which is encountered (starting at the begin of the list if the end is reached before finding a limited element).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, let's start with making the code more general, I'll come to the performance aspect later.

I generally don't use:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
```

Personally I like using a different name for the `cimport`ed package because it helps to keep the C side and the NumPy-Python side apart. So for this answer I'll use

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as cnp
```

Also I'll make `lower_limit` and `upper_limit` arguments of the function. Maybe these are defined statically (or globally) in your case but it makes the example more standalone. So the starting point is a slightly modified version of your code:

```
cpdef int search_1(cnp.ndarray[int] pool, int lower_limit, int upper_limit):
    cdef cnp.ndarray[int] limited
    limited = pool[(pool >= lower_limit) & (pool <= upper_limit)]
    return np.random.choice(limited)
```

One very nice feature in Cython is [fused types](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/src/userguide/fusedtypes.html#fused-types-templates), so you can easily generalize this function for different types. Your approach will only work for 32bit integer arrays (at least if `int` is 32bit on your computer). It is very easy to support more array types:

```
ctypedef fused int_or_float:
    cnp.int32_t
    cnp.int64_t
    cnp.float32_t
    cnp.float64_t

cpdef int_or_float search_2(cnp.ndarray[int_or_float] pool, int_or_float lower_limit, int_or_float upper_limit):
    cdef cnp.ndarray[int_or_float] limited
    limited = pool[(pool >= lower_limit) & (pool <= upper_limit)]
    return np.random.choice(limited)
```

Of course you can add more types if you want. The advantage is that the new version works where the old version failed:

```
>>> search_1(np.arange(100, dtype=np.float_), 10, 20)
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'int' but got 'double'
>>> search_2(np.arange(100, dtype=np.float_), 10, 20)
19.0
```

---

Now that it's more general let's take a look at what your function actually does:

- You create a boolean array where the elements are above the lower limit
- You create a boolean array where the elements are below the upper limit
- You create a boolean array by bitwise and of the two boolean arrays.
- You create a new array containing only the elements where the boolean mask is true
- You only extract one element from the last array

Why create so many arrays? I mean you could simply count how many elements are in within the limits, take a random integer between 0 and the number of elements within the limits and then take whatever element *would be* at that index in the result array.

```
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cpdef int_or_float search_3(cnp.ndarray[int_or_float] arr, int_or_float lower_bound, int_or_float upper_bound):
    cdef int_or_float element

    # Count the number of elements that are within the limits
    cdef Py_ssize_t num_valid = 0
    for index in range(arr.shape[0]):
        element = arr[index]
        if lower_bound <= element <= upper_bound:
            num_valid += 1

    # Take a random index
    cdef Py_ssize_t random_index = np.random.randint(0, num_valid)

    # Go through the array again and take the element at the random index that
    # is within the bounds
    cdef Py_ssize_t clamped_index = 0
    for index in range(arr.shape[0]):
        element = arr[index]
        if lower_bound <= element <= upper_bound:
            if clamped_index == random_index:
                return element
            clamped_index += 1
```

It won't be much faster but it will save a lot of memory. And because you don't have intermediate arrays you don't need memoryviews at all - but if you like you can just replace the `cnp.ndarray[int_or_float] arr` in the argument list with `int_or_float[:]` or even `int_or_float[::1] arr` and operate on the memoryview (it probably won't be faster but it also won't be slower).

I generally prefer numba to Cython (at least if just I am using it) so let's compare it to the numba version of that code:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit
def search_numba(arr, lower, upper):
    num_valids = 0
    for item in arr:
        if item >= lower and item <= upper:
            num_valids += 1

    random_index = np.random.randint(0, num_valids)

    valid_index = 0
    for item in arr:
        if item >= lower and item <= upper:
            if valid_index == random_index:
                return item
            valid_index += 1
```

And also to a `numexpr` variant:

```
import numexpr

np.random.choice(arr[numexpr.evaluate('(arr >= l) & (arr <= u)')])
```

Okay, let's do a benchmark:

```
from simple_benchmark import benchmark, MultiArgument

arguments = {2**i: MultiArgument([np.random.randint(0, 100, size=2**i, dtype=np.int_), 5, 50]) for i in range(2, 22)}
funcs = [search_1, search_2, search_3, search_numba, search_numexpr]

b = benchmark(funcs, arguments, argument_name='array size')
```

[image]

So by not using intermediate arrays you can be roughly 5 times faster and if you would use numba you could get another factor 5 (seems like I'm missing some possible Cython optimizations there, numba is typically ~2 times faster or as fast as Cython). So you could get it ~20 times faster with the numba solution.

`numexpr` isn't really comparable here, mostly because you cannot use the boolean array indexing there.

The differences will depend on the content of the array and the limits. You also have to measure the performance of your application.

---

As an aside: If the lower limit and the upper limit generally don't change the fastest solution would be to filter the array once and then just call `np.random.choice` on it several times. That could be *orders of magnitude faster*.

```
lower_limit = ...
upper_limit = ...
filtered_array = pool[(pool >= lower_limit) & (pool <= upper_limit)]

def search_cached():
    return np.random.choice(filtered_array)

%timeit search_cached()
2.05 µs ± 122 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

So almost 1000 times faster and doesn't need Cython or numba at all. But it's a special case that may not be useful for you.

---

The benchmark setup in case you want to do it yourself is here (based on a Jupyter Notebook/Lab, thus the `%`-symbols):

```
%load_ext cython

%%cython

cimport numpy as cnp
import numpy as np

cpdef int search_1(cnp.ndarray[int] pool, int lower_limit, int upper_limit):
    cdef cnp.ndarray[int] limited
    limited = pool[(pool >= lower_limit) & (pool <= upper_limit)]
    return np.random.choice(limited)

ctypedef fused int_or_float:
    cnp.int32_t
    cnp.int64_t
    cnp.float32_t
    cnp.float64_t

cpdef int_or_float search_2(cnp.ndarray[int_or_float] pool, int_or_float lower_limit, int_or_float upper_limit):
    cdef cnp.ndarray[int_or_float] limited
    limited = pool[(pool >= lower_limit) & (pool <= upper_limit)]
    return np.random.choice(limited)

cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cpdef int_or_float search_3(cnp.ndarray[int_or_float] arr, int_or_float lower_bound, int_or_float upper_bound):
    cdef int_or_float element
    cdef Py_ssize_t num_valid = 0
    for index in range(arr.shape[0]):
        element = arr[index]
        if lower_bound <= element <= upper_bound:
            num_valid += 1

    cdef Py_ssize_t random_index = np.random.randint(0, num_valid)

    cdef Py_ssize_t clamped_index = 0
    for index in range(arr.shape[0]):
        element = arr[index]
        if lower_bound <= element <= upper_bound:
            if clamped_index == random_index:
                return element
            clamped_index += 1

import numexpr
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

def search_numexpr(arr, l, u):
    return np.random.choice(arr[numexpr.evaluate('(arr >= l) & (arr <= u)')])

@nb.njit
def search_numba(arr, lower, upper):
    num_valids = 0
    for item in arr:
        if item >= lower and item <= upper:
            num_valids += 1

    random_index = np.random.randint(0, num_valids)

    valid_index = 0
    for item in arr:
        if item >= lower and item <= upper:
            if valid_index == random_index:
                return item
            valid_index += 1

from simple_benchmark import benchmark, MultiArgument

arguments = {2**i: MultiArgument([np.random.randint(0, 100, size=2**i, dtype=np.int_), 5, 50]) for i in range(2, 22)}
funcs = [search_1, search_2, search_3, search_numba, search_numexpr]

b = benchmark(funcs, arguments, argument_name='array size')

%matplotlib widget

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('ggplot')
b.plot()
```

Comment: I think, depending on ratio ` limited elements/all element`  it might be an advantage to save the found limited in a list and pick one from the list without the need to search it again.

Comment: @ead I actually had such an approach originally but at least in the benchmarks it was slower (even for good ratios). That's probably because the whole function is essentially bandwidth-limited and thus using an intermediate array might hurt performance substantially. And it always needs an intermediate array (more memory). Do you think I should include it in the answer? I thought it would be distracting but your comment made me realize that it could be useful to also mention discarded approaches.

Comment: At least I'm surprised, because with your approach you have to transfer the data 1.5 times (at average). With saving the results you would have to transfer only `1+ratio` times the data.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I'll award you the bounty in a few days unless other answers appear. I did not know that Numba could perform so well. I had tried looping through the array with bad results, I didn't think of storing just the number of matches instead of match indices, and if I understand correctly, your solution is faster since it does not require modifying any arrays while looping.

Comment: @ead I guess in case the ratio is very low the branch predictor for the "condition" (`lower_bound <= element <= upper_bound`) will be almost always correct which means that both loops have only very low overhead (the second array would increase the overhead in bandwidth and operations). But that's just guessing. One thing that I have noted but probably should've highlighted more is that the benchmarks might not be representative. The limits, the array contents and the drawn random number will significantly affect the performance.

Comment: @Waiski Yes part of the speedup is because the solution doesn't need to iterate several times over arrays (2 iterations instead of 4) and doesn't need temporary arrays (which include overhead because they have to be allocated and populated). However you really need to test the performance in your application. It might not be that much faster. Micro-benchmarks can profit from caching more than real applications and having random in the benchmark might offset the results as well.

Comment: @MSeifert Actually the real reason for not accepting it was that I stupidly asked this question (which is really important for my work project) just before leaving on vacation, so I haven't had the appropriate time to tend to it. I did quickly try your algorithm in Cython, and it reduced the running time of the total simulation by 25%, so I trust your solution is good. I would like to do proper benchmarks and update the question to better reflect what I should have asked (which is what you answered to), but I can't do that right now.